# Change SQL Server authentication mode using script

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am wondering how can someone change the sqlserver authentication mode by just a script?

I need a script to run in query window and change the authentication to mixed mode with it.
Any idea?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

For Windows only mode:

```
EXEC xp_instance_regwrite N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', 
    N'Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer', N'LoginMode', REG_DWORD, 1
```

Use `2` instead of `1` for mixed authentication.

You'll have to restart SQL Server after changing this setting.  You can't do that from T-SQL.  From the command prompt, it's something like `net stop mssqlserver` then `net start mssqlserver`.

Comment: You can check what mode you are running in using: exec master.sys.xp_loginconfig 'login mode'

Answer (score 3):

Whilst this isn't strictly an answer for this question I kept on running into this and similar posts when trying to find out how to **change a database to be partially contained using a script**.

If you're trying to do the same then you want:

```
ALTER DATABASE blah
SET CONTAINMENT=PARTIAL
```